# Share GraphQL schema between client and server

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo-client

I'm using the hooks such as `useQuery` from `@apollo/client` in my react app for querying my AppSync backend.  I have defined the schema in my Serverless AppSync project in a separate repo.  In order to get intellisense in my IDE for the graphql schema in my React project, i'll need to duplicate  my schema into my react app, and try and keep it up to date as I build out the schema on the backend.  What are people using/doing to get around the duplication of the same schema across client and server projects?  At the minute I have a `schema.graphql` file in both the react project and serverless project, however it feels like a 'smell' that i've missed something, or doing something wrong?  Any help is appreciated

Comment: Did you get any ideas for this?

Comment: Unfortunately in that project it remains as described in the question, i.e. I copy the schema from AppSync project to React project, and always that direction, where AppSync project is the truth. In a another project I've been working on, the developers there have a mono repo and they have a script that runs on save, that copies the schema from one directory to another. Still not the best, but it's an improvement and at least automated

Comment: Thank you for sharing. That's unfortunate and as you mention perhaps a custom script is the way to go when generating that schema or by watching on file change. Reassuring to hear that we're not alone in having this issue!

Answer (score 2):

I highly recommend using a code generation tool that uses your original schema as the source.

[GraphQL Code Generator](https://www.graphql-code-generator.com/docs/getting-started) is a package that you can easily incorporate into a React app or similar. Once you add it to your project, you can run `yarn graphql-codegen init` (assuming you use Yarn; there are options for npm, etc.) and it will ask a series of questions to generate a YAML configuration file. You then can add a command like `yarn generate` that references that file.

Here's an example of the config I created for my project:

```yaml
overwrite: true
schema: "http://localhost:8080/query"
documents: "./src/**/*.graphql"
generates:
  src/generated/graphql.tsx:
    plugins:
      - "typescript"
      - "typescript-operations"
      - "typescript-react-query"
  ./graphql.schema.json:
    plugins:
      - "introspection"
```

When you run the `yarn generate` command, it fetches your schema from your running back-end service (you'll need to make sure your service has GraphQL introspection enabled), combines that with your client-side queries, and then generates everything necessary to interact with your service. In my case, I use `react-query`, and it creates a per-operation wrapper around `useQuery`, e.g., `useWidgetsQuery`. It works great.

I have no affiliation with the project, I'm just a fan.

If you also use code generation on the back end (through another project, depending on your back-end language), it means you can write your schema, etc. once and then generate a huge amount of types and wiring that is easy to keep in sync across projects.